# What should we look for in our first postdoc position?

Tags: application, funding, postdocs, international, government-institutes

What are the opportunities that we should aim for while searching for a postdoc position for a researcher with and without a family in theoretical particle physics? I want to know also the qualities that one should look for in a host organisation while applying for a fellowship.

For example, the host's research interest, the Institute's work policy towards short-term researchers and international activity of the research group. What are the intricacies that should not be compromised with and what can be compromised with?

Comment: Many of those are personal (or family) preferences. How you weight them is likely different than how I did.

Comment: I think this question is broad and opinion-based question. This also depends on the individual's preferences.

Comment: It is true everyone have their own set of reasons. but one thing that is important is the international activity of the research group, for sure. But you also need to make sure that this will apply to your project e.g. is the project too experimental, risky, will you be working in isolation? Also, I would check the alumni of the lab and see where they are now. I chose another lab in the last moment despite it didn't check these boxes and I kind of regret it now, but I got some other aspects such as networking, and a relatively stress free life.

Comment: It is also important to get a sense of whether you will be treated as someone temporary filling in a project position or whether the advisor will elevate you and support you for new opportunities. Of course this is difficult to know beforehand.

Comment: @dusa thanks! Is there a way to access this information? Or networking and knowing the right people is the only way to do it?

Comment: Well for research activities check their papers, citations, co-authors. It is an indicator but doesn't tell the whole story. Checking where the alumni is - I think a great indicator - you just need to google a lot. One thing I learnt the hard way is that talking to people in the lab might be useless and misleading. A guy who portrayed a positive image left only 2 months in after I joined, not on great terms either. I imagine most people in the field won't know much, and the people in the lab won't really be too open about the drawbacks.

Comment: Well, ask anyway but take the comments with a grain of salt. If someone asked me I would be more realistic and objective, but it is not the case for many.

Comment: Also note that post doc openings are much lower this year so finance/family/location/security/work-life balance are legit reasons as well, particularly this year.

Comment: Yes, so that is why I am apprehensive about post-doc openings in the next 2 years, but hopefully, things will stabilize over some time soon.